# I have an empty string of multiple keys that I convert into html and print out on the screen, how do I add a checkbox for each key?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, salesforce

I have a JavaScript function that creates an empty string, grabs key values, converts them to their html form which is what I want to print and adds break lines. I want each line to have its own check box where I have $("#checkboxConsent). It just prints out object object, its html form. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var consentString = "";//creating empty string for consents
    for(var grabbingKeyLines in data.consentText.consentLines)
        consentString += '<br>' + $('#checkBoxConsent') + (data.consentText.consentLines[grabbingKeyLines] + '<br>') 
         }
                    
    $('#stateConsentLines').html(consentString);//show string
```

Comment: You'll need to show us what `data.consentText.consentLines` is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus is it an object that has a key and associated with a value. 
[0: "some text",
 1 : "more text"] and I am just grabbing the text associated with the key

Comment: `[0: "some text", 1 : "more text"]` is not valid JavaScript. Do you mean `{0: "some text", 1 : "more text"}`?   `[]` denotes an Array (which doesn't have keys), while `{}` denotes an object that does, but if you just want sequential numeric keys that start from 0, then you should be using an array.

Comment: its a json, and putting the json into the empty string

Comment: Well, first, that's not valid JSON. Even if it was, you'll need to pass that string as an argument to `JSON.parse()` before it will be accessible as a JS object.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing for your JSON (`[0: "some text", 1 : "more text"]`) is not valid JSON.

- `[]` denotes an array and arrays have numeric indices, not keys.
- `{}` denotes an object and objects have string keys.

One simple way to know that you have valid JSON is to create the JSON yourself using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as in this example:

```js
// Keep in mind that console.log() outputs a string, so while the 
// console won't show it, you must realize that the output you see
// would have single quotes around the whole output.

// Example of JSON from an array. Produces: '["some text","more text"]'
console.log(JSON.stringify(["some text", "more text"]));

// Example of JSON from an object. Produces: '{"key1":"some text","key2":"more text"}'
console.log(JSON.stringify({key1: "some text", key2: "more text"}));
```

Given what you are showing in your string, it seems like you need an array, rather than an object (you are showing numeric indices that go with the data).

Next, even if your string was valid JSON, you'd need to pass it into [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in order to turn it back into a JavaScript array or object before you can work with it as such.

```js
// Parsing a JSON string into a JS array:
console.log(JSON.parse('["some text", "more text"]'));
/* Produces: 
[
  "some text",
  "more text"
]
*/

// Parsing a JSON string into a JS object:
console.log(JSON.parse('{"key1":"some text","key2":"more text"}'));
/* Produces: 
{
  "key1": "some text",
  "key2": "more text"
}
*/
```

Now all of that is just to get you to a point where you have either an array or an object that you can work with in JavaScript. To your specific question, you then need to iterate through that array or object to access the individual elements that it contains.

```js
// Parsing a JSON string into a JS array:
let ary = JSON.parse('["some array text", "more array text"]');

// Parsing a JSON string into a JS object:
let obj = JSON.parse('{"key1":"some object text","key2":"more object text"}');

// Loop over the array and create output with a checkbox before each item
let output1 = ""; // Will hold resulting HTML
ary.forEach(function(item){
  output1 += "<input type='checkbox'>" + item + "<br>";
});
document.querySelector("#out1").innerHTML = output1;

// Loop over the object and create output with a checkbox before each item
let output2 = ""; // Will hold resulting HTML
for(var item in obj){
  output2 += "<input type='checkbox'>" + obj[item] + "<br>";
};
document.querySelector("#out2").innerHTML = output2;
```

```html
<div id="out1"></div>

<div id="out2"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use `$("#checkBoxConsent").clone().attr('id', '')[0].outerHTML` instead of `$("#checkBoxConsent")` :

```
var consentString = "";//creating empty string for consents
for(var grabbingKeyLines in data.consentText.consentLines)
    consentString += '<br>' + $("#checkBoxConsent").clone().attr('id', '')[0].outerHTML + (data.consentText.consentLines[grabbingKeyLines] + '<br>') 
     }
                
$('#stateConsentLines').html(consentString);//show string
```

`$("#checkBoxConsent").clone().attr('id', '')[0].outerHTML` this clones the example checkbox to a new element and remove its `id` so it wont be duplicated than getthe html text of the element by `outerHTML`.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that `$("#checkBoxConsent")` is an object and not an element that has an attribute.

Comment: yes `$("#checkBoxConsent")` is an object of JQuery referring to an html element, and if you want to add it like string you should use `outerHTML()`, so what the problem ?

Comment: You're not following. `$("#checkBoxConsent")` is an ***object*** (more specifically it's a JQuery wrapped set object). It's not an ***element*** and the OP is trying to access this object as if it were an element and that's why he's getting `[Object object]` in his output.

Comment: yes i did understand but if he use the function `outerHTML` he will not get ***Object*** but he will get the actual html of the element as ***string***, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), and actually i did a mistake on the syntax of implemeting that function, i edited the post now and fixed it.